# How to change Apache2 default directory in Docker

Tags: docker, apache2

I am able to set up a localhost server using a Docker container made with `httpd:2.4` and it shows the default "It Works!" page. I have my own /var/www/html directory from a production server and want to emulate it in the container. How do I change the default Apache directory so that it uses my folder? Or if I can't do that, then where can I copy my folder so that apache uses it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount it as a volume or copy when building.

If you are using a Dockerfile, add this to your docker image, then build and run.

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./var/www/html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

If you are not using a dockerfile:

```
$ docker run -dit --name my-apache-app -p 8080:80 -v ./var/www/html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4
```

make sure to replace `./var/www/html` with your local path for your folder.
You can open a terminal inside the folder and type `pwd`. Use the output as your value.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Docker file-:

```
FROM httpd:latest
RUN  rm /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/*
COPY /xyz.html  /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

EXPOSE 80
```

use your file in place of xyz.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).